# iOS 4 app flickers and crashes when returning from background mode

Tags: iphone, background, ios4, multitasking

I just converted an iPhone OS 3 app to iOS 4, and once in a while, the screen will flicker and then turn black when the app returns from background mode. Has anyone else experienced this?

I finally resorted to terminating the app before it enters background mode. This is definitely a temporary band aid:

```
- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(UIApplication *)application {
   // kill the app rather than letting it go into BG
   exit(0);
}
```

Any advice would be great. Thanks.

Comment: Just set the "UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend" to YES in your info.plist to keep your app from going into the background. I agree with Kendall, tho, it sounds like you're not recovering from a memory warning as you transition to the background.

Answer (score 1):

What is the system doing when it enters the foreground?

It sounds a lot like a memory warning may be triggering views to unload in odd ways.  I'd do some testing in the simulator around firing memory warnings when in various screens.

I'm pretty sure your exit() trick would block app store submission.

Comment: I can reproduce this flicker problem from several different views in my app. I've made sure that every applicable file has didReceiveMemoryWarning(), and I put a breakpoint on every single one. However, the app doesn't stop on any breakpoint when this problem occurs during debugging on the phone.

I was afraid that exit() would be frowned upon. :(

Answer (score 1):

you can disable backgrounding using the info.plist  UIApplicationExitsOnSuspend

You might be running into a "Failed to resume in time" error .. check the crash report via Organizer in XCode.